# C# Unity - Getting which function affects a GameObject

Tags: unity, c#

I have this little code that moves a `GameObject` over time:

```
 public void Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
     {
         StartCoroutine(_Move(from, to, overTime));
     }
     IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
     {
         Vector2 original = from.position;
         float timer = 0.0f;
         while (timer < overTime)
         {
             float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
             from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
             timer += Time.deltaTime;
             yield return null;
         }
     }
```

Which is easy as it is, I plan to use it for UI animations. However, things get interesting when I wish to use this for a bit more complex animations, or I want it to stop upon restart.

**More complex animations:**

I click a button which then moves to the side and bounches back. For this I need to know when the exact same method finished moving the button so I can restart it to bounce back.

**Stop upon restart:**

Say I hover my mouse over a button which moves then. However, if it's still moving, I want its current animation to stop, and a new one to start. For both of these I need to know which function affects which GameObject so I can manage that. Question is, how? Shall I use one script on each of the animated components which affects only that one? Or if I could use only one script on the whole Canvas, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Complex Animations:

To know when a coroutine finished executing, you can pass a callback to it as one of its arguments, which it invokes once it's done (or at any other point throughout its execution), like so:

```
private IEnumerator DummyCoroutine(Action onCompletedCallback) 
{
    // Do something here...

    onCompletedCallback.Invoke();
}
```

### Stop Upon Restart:

1) Create a global variable for the coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator dummyCoroutine;
```

2) Make sure the coroutine nullifies that global variable once it finishes executing:

```
private IEnumerator DummyCoroutine() 
{
    // Do something here...

    dummyCoroutine = null;
}
```

3) Whenever you want to start the coroutine, do a null-check on the global variable. If it's not null, then the coroutine is still running. Call StopCoroutine() on it to stop it. Then, either way, create a new instance of the coroutine, assign it to the global variable, and start it:

```
private void StartMyDummyCoroutine()
{
    if (dummyCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(dummyCoroutine);
    }

    dummyCoroutine = DummyCoroutine();
    StartCoroutine(dummyCoroutine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I thought about firing off an event at the end of my coroutine and I can subscribe whatever I want to it, thus chaining my animations. Doable?

Comment: Absolutely. That's what I meant by the first part of my answer. You might also get away with including the whole complex animation in that one coroutine. You can use booleans or states to keep track of the animation's state.